# Java Interface conventions with getters and setters

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on an application in which I have two fairly similar object classes whose fields need to be normalized.  Many of the fields that need to be normalized are shared by both of these classes, but there are some that pertain only to one or the other.

I was thinking to create an interface with getters and setters for all of the fields that need to be normalized, that way I could pass both objects to the same class and access the fields / set the normalized values via the interface methods.  Would this be considered bad convention?

Below is simplified example-- the objects I am normalizing will only ever be read from once the normalization is completed.  Thanks in advance!

```
 class A implements C{

     T x;
     T y;
     T z; 
     ...
 }

 class B implements C{
    T x;
    T y;
    T k;   // no 'z', above has no k
    ....
 }

 interface C {
     public T getX();
     public void setX(T x);

     public T getY();
     public void setY(T y);

     public T getZ();
     public void setZ(T z);

     public T getK();
     public void setK(T k);
 }
```

Comment: Why not create a (possibly abstract) parent class with x and y, a child class with only z, and a child class with only k ?

Comment: Yes yes I was thinking of this-- both objects have several fields and already extend another abstract class that is extended by a ton of OTHER objects.  To do it this way I would need to create an additional layer in between (the interface would be a quicker fix, but it feels a little ugly which is why I made the post!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is properly documented saying `A` does not support

```
public T getK();
public void setK(T k);
```

and `B` does not support

```
public T getZ();
public void setZ(T z);
```

then I think you can go ahead with this design.

And, also construct `UnsupportedOperationException` with the specified detail message for the classes that doesn't support some of the methods of `C`. For example,

```
class A implements C{

     T x;
     T y;
     T z; 
     ...
     public T getK(){
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("YOUR MESSAGE");
     }

}
```

Comment: is this not a very bad design and contradicting the concept of interface and making it unsafe to call a method from an interface reference?

Comment: @BlackPanther Yes, it is kind of contradictory. That is why I mentioned that the implementation classes should be properly documented saying about the methods that they does not support.

Comment: yes yes, i completely agree.. but this approach, if the documentations are not maintained properly, will lead to problems. i just thought having a class with the `K` and another class with `Z` and make them extend a base class would be a better design.

Comment: @BlackPanther Agree. My answer will work if classes were documented properly so that the clients using the implementations of `C` would know what they are permitted to do with a given implementation of `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't implementing an interface and providing an empty implementation a bad design issue? though you document it, it goes against the concept of interface and is inconsistent as you may have an empty implementation of one method in one class, and another implementation in another class and the code will become inconsistent in the long run, making it unsafe..  consider this

```
interface iSample {
   void doThing1();
   void doThing2();
   void doThing3();
}

class sClass1 implements iSample {

   void doThing1() {  //doThing1 code }
   void doThing2() {  //doThing2 code }
   void doThing3() { } // empty implementation

}

class sClass2 implements iSample {

   void doThing1() {  //doThing1 code }
   void doThing2() { }  // empty implementation
   void doThing3() { //doThing2 code }

}

class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

     testing(new sClass1());
     testing(new sClass2());


  }

  public void testing(iSample s) {
     // you would have no idea here which object has omitted which method.
     s.doThing1();  
     s.doThing2();  
     s.doThing3();  
  }
```

as stated above you would have no idea which object has omitted which method and inconsistency prevails.

Comment: This is why I had reservations about the interface approach.  However, the processor classes responsible for normalizing each field don't need to care what type of object they are dealing with--they'll simply check if the passed in object has a non null attribute and if it does it will perform the normalization.  If it doesn't it won't do anything.  Once the objects have been normalized, they are written to a database and never touched again.

Comment: if that is the case, then you can proceed with fulfilling the contract with an UnSupportedOperationException and handle the exception as @Debojit Saikia mentioned. but still you can use a base class and have a separate child class that has the `Z` and another class with `K`, that would be a better design and it provides a global approach

Comment: understood-- the interface is quicker fix. but I agree that the base class is better design.  If in the future more fields need to be normalized it would be easier to scale with a base class

Comment: @shaunvxc : exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your description, you would have empty methods inside both of your classes because you won't need them. `class A` would leave `getK` and `setK` unimplemented, and `class B` would do the same with `getZ` and `setZ`.

In this case it might be best to use a parent class that has `x` and `y`, and leave the implementation of `z` and `k` local to `class A` and `class B`, respectively.

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it the more it seems like I need to make a base class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Highly similar classes?

This sounds like a really good time to design for inheritance.  Note that designing for inheritance should be a really deliberate decision ... because there's a right way to do it which will make your API a joy to use and a wrong way which can make your API a hassle to use.

You can also use an interface-based type system as you are suggesting.  This has the advantage of being applicable to classes that may not otherwise be related.

Or you can do both.

I suggest that you capture the essence of the relationship in your classes and describe that as the **contract** for your interface-based type system.

Then, I suggest that you produce a skeletal implementation of your contract in an **abstract** skeletal implementation class.  Your concrete classes can inherit from your skeletal implementation and, if done well, will inherit much of the behavior and state that describes the essence of your contract.

Note that you should use your interface as the type designation for all your objects, much like we do with the Java Collections API.  It is not encouraged to declare a parameter type as `void myFunc(HashMap m)`;  the best practice is to declare `void myFunc(Map m)`.  In the latter case, Map represents the interface-based type system for all the different implementors of the Map contract.